# If a variable is created within the scope of a function that returns a function that uses that variable. Is it possible to acces that variable outside

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
function creatPrintNumFunction()
{
  var num= 12;
  return function printNum()
  {
     console.log(num);
  }
}

 var printer = creatPrintNumFunction();
printer.num =13; //this part doesn't work but is there a way to access this Num variable Outside the creatPrintNumFunction, The printer function must be finding the num variable from somewhere.
printer();
```

So how can I get this code to print 13 instead of 12 **most importantly with out changing any of the code of the createPrintNumFunction().**

For more context on what I really need to use this theory for. I'm using an external module express-sessions in node.js that I don't want to change. There is this 'store' variable where all the sessions are stored that I need to access only problem is that it's created within a function.There is another way i could access it but it's not really convenient

Comment: As it stands, your code doesn't use the `num` local variable; it prints the `store` global variable, which is not defined. I suspect you've over-simplified the code when posting your question.

Comment: sorry i edited to fix that it was a distraction mistake

Comment: Wit h the code you've shown, there is no way to modify the `num` local variable from outside of the `creatPrintNumFunction` function.

Comment: yea now i know what i'm trying to do is impossible, thx any way

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So, the comment you wrote about printNum() function being able to access the `num` variable somehow is due to JavaScript closures. Closures are an important JavaScript topic which I would recommend looking at some online resources or this stackoverflow post [JavaScript closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) to learn about. Essentially when you return the printNum function from createPrintNumFunction, the printNum function will remember the num variable that was declared in createPrintNumFunction. But to answer your question of whether you can access the variable outside of the scope it was declared in, then the answer is no. An outer scope cannot access variables from an inner scope. Inner scopes can access variables from outer scopes. So, unless you are keeping track of the `num` variable from outside of the scope that it was declared in, you won't be able to access the value `num` holds outside of the scope it was declared in.

So, here you can change the value of `num` inside of the printNum function itself like this:

```js
function creatPrintNumFunction() {
  var num = 12;
  return function printNum() {
    num = 13;
    console.log(num);
  };
}

var printer = creatPrintNumFunction();
printer.num = 13; //this part doesn't work but is there a way to access this Num variable Outside the creatPrintNumFunction, The printer function must be finding the num variable from somewhere.
printer();
```

You could define a global variable that keeps track of the `num` variable. Then through the scope chain the value used inside of the printNum function for the `num` variable will resolve to the value your global variable currently contains like so:

```js
var num = 12;

function creatPrintNumFunction() {
  return function printNum() {
    console.log(num);
  };
}

var printer = creatPrintNumFunction();
num = 13; //this part doesn't work but is there a way to access this Num variable Outside the creatPrintNumFunction, The printer function must be finding the num variable from somewhere.
printer();
```

I'm sure there are other methods to go about this as well but I hope that one of the above methods fits your need.

Comment: thx a lot especially for guiding me to the JavaScript closures explanations. I feel there are many of these basic language things I'm not understanding about javascript that are blocking me from understanding how lots of the modules of node.js work.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for something like this?

```js
function creatPrintNumFunction() {
  const f = function printNum() {
    console.log(f.num);
  };
  f.num = 12;           // set .num property to initial value
  return f;             // return function "printNum"
}

var printer = creatPrintNumFunction();
printer.num = 13;
printer();

printer.num = 42;
printer();
```

Comment: that involves changing the code within creatPrintNumFunction() which i want to avoid changing but i might change it anyway,

Answer (score 0):

> There is this 'store' variable where all the sessions are stored that I need to access only problem is that it's created within a function. There is another way i could access it but it's not really convenient

No there is no way to access `store` without modifying the code. And you shouldn't modify the code of an external module, because `store` is likely made inaccessible for a reason. Changing the code might result in a code base that would prevent you from updating the `express-sessions`.

Having the need to do that sounds like an XY-Problem.

---

If it is your code and you want to allow the variable to be accessed there are different ways to do that. You for sure could move `var num` outside of `creatPrintNumFunction` (as described in the [answer of alonealgorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71024537/1960455) but that breaks the encapsulation you had before. Whether that is a good idea or not depends on the actual use case. But you need to be aware that if you do that that every "print" function returned from `creatPrintNumFunction` then uses the same variable.

Let's say you don't want to move `num` out of the scope of `creatPrintNumFunction` because every "print" function returned from `creatPrintNumFunction` should have its own `num` variable.

What then you could do is to create another function (e.g. `set`) within `creatPrintNumFunction` that can change `num` and assign this function as a property to the function you return from `creatPrintNumFunction`.

```js
function creatPrintNumFunction() {
  var num = 12;
  
  // both "set" and "printNum" create here
  // have a closure over the same "num" variable
  function set(val) {
    num = val;
  }

  function printNum() {
    console.log(num);
  }

  // the "set" function is assigned as a parameter to your
  // printNum function
  printNum.set = set;

  return printNum;
}

var printerA = creatPrintNumFunction();
var printerB = creatPrintNumFunction();
printerA.set(13)
printerB.set(23)
printerA();
printerB();
```

The advantage of this approach is that you don't expose `num` and you can control in your `set` function how/if `num` can be changed.

Comment: thx that methode you use though still modifies the content of the creatPrintNumFunction() function which i wanted to avoid,  alonealgorithm seems to be pretty sure there is no way to do what i want to do with out changing creatPrintNumFunction() so i'm going to trust him.

Comment: @Cavernhead Yes, there is no way to access `num` without changing the code. And if the authors of `express-session` choose to make it not accessible then this is done for a reason. One reason could be that they don't want to give any guarantee about how `store` looks like and therefore only allow access to it through an API.